# ORA-02070: database INVWARE does not support in this context

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, merge, insert-update

**Background:**
I am wanting to run this merge inside a procedure on a schedule.  I have to insert new data into the sql database table and if the data exist, I am wanting to update the quantities.

**Problem:**
I am trying to do a merge from an Oracle database to a sql database and getting an error (see the title of this question). I have tried using the merge with the same sql script used to create the view and it returned the same error.

**Question:**
Is the problem something in my code (see below)?

```
MERGE INTO "receipt_details"@invware d
USING (
SELECT *
FROM raf_po_receiving_details_v
WHERE last_update_date >= '1-AUG-2013' ) s
ON ( "po_header_id" = s.po_header_id
 and "po_line_id" = s.po_line_id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
   SET "purchased_qty" = s.purchased_qty,
       "qty_received" = s.qty_received,
       "balance_remaining" = s.balance_remaining,
       "qty_billed" = s.qty_billed
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ( "warehouse_code", "po_number", "po_header_id", 
                           "vendor_name", "line_num", 
                           "item_code", "purchased_qty", "qty_received",
                           "rcv_by", "balance_remaining", "qty_billed", 
                           "closed_code", "rec_date", "need_by_date", "po_line_id" )
VALUES (s.warehouse_code, s.po_number, s.po_header_id, s.vendor_name,
    s.line_num, s.item_code, s.purchased_qty, s.qty_received, s.rcv_by,
    s.balance_remaining, s.qty_billed, s.closed_code, s.rec_date, s.need_by_date, po_line_id);
```

Comment: On the sql server, I have the following
warehouse_code varchar(500), po_number varchar(500), po_header_id int, vendor_name varchar(500), line_num int, item_code varchar(500), purchased_qty int, qty_received int, rcv_by varchar(500), balance_remaining int, qty_billed int, closed_code varchar(500), rec_date date, need_by_date date and po_line_id int.

Comment: warehouse_code varchar2(150 Byte), po_number varchar2( 20 Byte), po_header_id number, vendor_name varchar2( 240 Byte), line_num number, item_code varchar2( 40 Byte), purchased_qty number, qty_received number, rcv_by varchar2( 240 Byte), balance_remaining number, qty_billed number, closed_code varchar2( 25 Byte), rec_date Date, need_by_date Date, po_line_id number  

Sql Server is 2012 Enterprise.